# How do I set up a container so Emacs LSP can run a Python IDE with pyright?

Tags: lsp-mode, docker

I am trying to update old python code using a TensorFlow v1 container (I will eventually port it to either TensorFlow v2 or PyTorch).

I have an emacs Python environment already set up and used locally based on LSP, pyright, flycheck, pyvenv and anaconda-mode. I have added docker-tramp to use the container environment.

Investigating, I am able to connect emacs to the container and navigate using eShell. However, although I have tried installing pyright in the container using pip install pyright before connecting with tramp-emacs, it appears the install is put in a site-packages folder which isn't in the PATH variable for the container. When I add it prior to connection, pyright still isn't recognised. I can see the folder called pyright and inside a set of python scripts.

As things stand, when I connect to a file of python code in the container (volume mapped to my python workspace), LSP springs to life but advises no language server is available.

Can anyone advise:

- How do I set up a container so my Emacs session outside of the container can enter the container and my emacs-lsp can run a Python IDE with pyright using the python and modules in the container?

In answering, can you be sure to address:

- How should I install pyright so that it can be seen by the docker-tramp connection?
- If anything else needs installing on the container, are there any 'gotchas' I need to look out for or best practices I should adhere to?

Comment: Please pose only one question per post.

Comment: Hey @Drew - I have edited to make the question clear. I have included other points that I would need to understand for any answers to that question. Happy to take any further edit suggestions if needed.

Comment: Thanks. But I still vote to close, because the question is, I think, too broad for this site. You're essentially looking for some general advice in approach etc. This site is more for specific how-to or specific understanding questions. My suggestion would be to try a discussion site such as Reddit. But maybe you'll get lucky here...

Comment: Regarding "it appears the install is put in a site-packages folder which isn't in the PATH variable for the container", does adding that directory to your `tramp-remote-path` help?

Comment: Hi @phils I'm afraid that didn't help. I will park this in the 'too hard' basket for now.